# Pandas lambda apply in two columns that are lists in an efficient way

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, performance

I have a dataset like this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({
    'users_list':[["us1",  "us2", "us3", "us5", "us5"], ['us2', "us3", 'us2']], 
    'users_tuples': [[('us1', 'us2'), ('us2', 'us3'), ('us5', 'us1'), ('us5', 'us1')], [('us2', 'us3'), ('us3', 'us2')]]})
```

First I get a list of all users without repetition, like this:

```
all_users = sorted(list(set(sum([x for x in d['users_list']],[]))))
```

And then I have is this below:

```
for us in all_users:
   d[us] = d.apply(lambda x :  [1 if (a, us) in x['users_tuples'] else 0 for a in x['users_list']], 1)
```

But the answer I got is a list:

```
us1              us2              us3             us5
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1] [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]        [0, 1, 0]      [1, 0, 1]       [0, 0, 0]
```

And I want the sum of each one of these, so it will be:

```
us1 us2 us3 us5
2   1   1   0
0   1   2   0
```

I know that to have this i can do:

```
for us in all_users:
       d[us] = d.apply(lambda x :  sum([1 if (a, us) in x['users_tuples'] else 0 for a in x['users_list']]), 1)
```

But I think is not efficient at all of these transformations and I was wondering if is there a more efficient way to do them.

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: Yes, I've update with more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences, then convert that to a dataframe and use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and fill missing values with 0 using [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
def f(x):
    l = map(itemgetter(1), x) # equivalent to `(v for _,v in x)` or `map(lambda v: v[1], x)`
    return Counter(l)

(pd.DataFrame(d['users_tuples'].map(f).tolist()).
    reindex(set(chain.from_iterable(d['users_list'])),axis=1).fillna(0))

   us2  us5  us3  us1
0    1  0.0    1  2.0
1    1  0.0    1  0.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Can you explain why this is more efficient?

Comment: using `for-loop` on a dataframe is significantly slower than using vectorized solution. And `sum([x for x in d['users_list']],[])` don't use this flatten a list it's very inefficient and quadratic runtime. use `chain/ chain.from_iterable`. And you test yourself by using `timeit` ;) [`read about it here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/12416453) @CatarinaNogueira

Comment: And `df.apply` over axis 1 is also inefficient and should be used as last resort. Read more about it [here posted by cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/12416453) and you are using `df.apply` in every iteration @CatarinaNogueira